# Submit multiple isolated forms in Rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, forms

I'm looking for a way to submit multiple forms generated on the fly with form_for, but haven't succeeded so far.

It's a sign-up sheet for an event, where a mother can sign herself up (with one form), as well as her kids (with another distinct form), if she has some. So a user#show page could have a single form (for the mother) or 4, 5 etc.

Here's what I have. The forms work fine when I have them with `remote: true` and a submit button by each. But the single button with a script to submit all forms at once doesn't function...

```
  <% if current_user == @user %>
    <% if @user.children %>
      <% @children.each do |child| %>
        <div class="attendance-form">
          <%= form_for(child, html: {id: "form-enfant-#{child.first_name}"}) do |f| %>
            <%= f.label child.first_name %>
            <%= f.check_box :attendance %>
          <% end %>
        </div>
      <% end %>
    <% end %>
    <%= form_for current_user, html: {id: "form-parent"} do |f| %>
      <%= f.label "Me" %>
      <%= f.check_box :attendance %>
    <% end %>

  <% end %>

  <div class="actions">
    <a id="submit">Submit</a>
  </div>



<script>
  $(function() {
    $('#submit').click(function() {
     <% @children.each do |child| %>
       <%= ("$('#form-enfant-" + child.first_name + "').submit();") %>
     <% end %>
      $('#form-parent').submit();
    });
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not submit more than one form unless you use AJAX. So either make them remote again, either write some code to serialize the form data and post it to the server.

Instead of just calling `submit` call something like this:

```
$.post('/the/form/specific/url/', $('#form-x').serialize())
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need here is a combination of both [the concept of single table inheritance](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Inheritance.html) and [the concept of nested forms](http://www.amooma.de/screencasts/2015-01-22-nested_forms-rails-4.2/).

Single  table inheritance will enable you to have many types of user: ( mother, father, son, daughter, etc...)

while,

Nested forms will enable you to be able to have associated models in a form. I.E: a form for a mother, and a nested form for her children, with a single submit button doing the work for you...

I think you should be able to combine these two concepts to get a very good result on what you are trying to do.

Good luck :-)